# Retrieval of RavenDb Etags is slow

Tags: ravendb, etag

We're starting to use a distributed caching strategy on top of our central RavenDb database.
As a part of this strategy, we're retrieving Etag of a document from RavenDb and a value of the object from local Azure blob storage cache.

Our objects are changed extremely infrequently (10-100 object changes per day) but are retrieved extremely frequently (about 5000 object retrievals a minute and growing)

This is a multi-threaded environment, and internal RavenDb cache is not big enough to store all objects in the AggresiveCache mode.

Anyway, we're seeing terrible times with retrieval of Etags from Raven.  Between 1 and 10 seconds (!!!???) What are we doing wrong?  This is the code

```
return _session.Advanced.DocumentStore.DatabaseCommands.Head(id).Etag;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making a request per call, which means that you have to pay a lot of the cost of already fetching the document.
It will likely be cheaper to just load the document directly instead of doing the Head

Comment: no way to just get the Etag without loading the full doc? Makes no sense to get full doc when Etag is probably stored separately or at least with special provisions in Raven

Comment: Total cost is pretty much the same, unless the doc is very large